# Why has my question regarding PHP operators been put on hold?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

I was wondering if someone can direct me in the right direction as to why [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385279/php-what-is-the-difference-between-using-instead-of) was put on hold.

Comment: What is the actual practical problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: "*Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise*"

Comment: If you really want to know, you should ask "is there any difference" between using the two operators. That has a simple factual answer. It may also give you some insight into how people choose which to use.

Comment: Though as it turns out (no surprise to me) that has been asked and answered already, and was listed in the related questions from your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294579/difference-between-and-in-php?rq=1 I highly suspect this link was shown to you while you were typing your question. Had you clicked it, you would have learned what you wanted immediately and saved a lot of trouble.

Comment: One could also have voted to close it citing: _There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs._

Comment: One minor off-topic nitpick: could you please not start your titles on Stack Overflow with a tag-name? It's not necessary. Thanks. ;)

Comment: @KhanqueredPro This is everyone's site, assuming people remain civil (as in this case) it's not really appropriate to tell people to stop contributing

Comment: @KhanqueredPro you know, at first I didn't downvote you here. But seeing your attitude towards a rather friendly user who is only trying to help, I changed my mind.

Comment: @KhanqueredPro Pro-tip: just let it go. Focus on this particular question of yours and ignore the rest.

Comment: @Bart thank you for the tip

Answer (score 14):

Your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20385279/1) was:

> I'm curios to know, why some would use <> instead of != ?
>
> is it a preference style?
>
> do other languages utilize this operator <> ?
>
> thank you

Asking *why* people make a choice is subjective. There isn't a single correct answer – each person may have their own reasoning. Hence this was closed using the appropriate close reason.

Since the original closing, the question has been edited in a [much more healthy direction](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20385279/4):

> What is the difference between using `<>` and `!=` in PHP?
>
> Do other languages utilize a similar `<>` operator?

This is now an objective concrete question that can be answered. If I were nit-picking, I'd point out the second sub-question is a little open-ended and vague, but it shouldn't be too hard to find a few mainstream languages that use that operator as an example.

Comment: your answer is spot on! but be careful about the reasons for downvotes on question - usually they reflect (*or at least should be*) no research shown, usefulness, and clearness

Comment: however it is a dupe, so if it is reopened it should be closed as a dupe to be signpost to the existing question.

Comment: The second part is definitely too broad (in my opinion, at least).

Answer (score 5):

The main reason is that the answers will reflect the opinions of the folk answering rather than anything factual.

See Jon Skeet's [blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on asking the perfect question.