# Why are these question put on hold?

Tags: support, reopen-closed

the other day I asked why was my question put on hold and someone end up putting my question on hold.

now I have two questions on hold and I am asking the 3rd.

how does one remove the hold, I have already reworded my questions?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385279/what-is-the-difference-between-using-instead-of

[Why has my question regarding PHP operators been put on hold?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210208/why-has-my-question-regarding-php-operators-been-put-on-hold)

Comment: Please clarify **which** questions, on **which** site, you are talking about.

Comment: It probably still shouldn't be reopened or undeleted because now it's a duplicate of this question (I believe) - [What is the difference between <> and !=?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9671785) The "Do other languages" part isn't duplicated, but it's too broad.

Comment: While I don't condone the OP's attitude in the other Meta question, this kind of stuff makes me lose faith in the SO community. Was it really necessary to give the original question *8* downvotes, and close it? Even though *anybody* with a tiny bit of good will could have edited it into shape (which Bart then did)? Or at least pointed to the highly-upvoted duplicate, [What is the difference between <> and !=](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9671785)? Why did three users see it necessary to delete the question, *after* it was edited into shape, instead of pointing to the duplicate?

Comment: The question is reopened now and I voted to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Pëkka I found [another duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294579/difference-between-and-in-php). Between those two, which is the best main question (to close the other one as a duplicate of)? There's also [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589391/php-operator) [others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956362/whats-the-difference-between-and) that need to be closed. (Symbol Hound for the win)

Comment: @Dukeling ha! We really need some kind of a visual duplicate connector tool....

Comment: Voting to reopen, because it's not a duplicate. The supposed duplicate doesn't answer the awful "please list every language that has used `<>` as an operator" question; this question deserves its chance to be closed as Too Broad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why has my question regarding PHP operators been put on hold?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210208/why-has-my-question-regarding-php-operators-been-put-on-hold)

Comment: @Wooble So don't primarily link to a good question that answers the valid part of the question, just because of the invalid part? That doesn't seem right, at all. (A comment saying the invalid part is invalid and/or an edit to remove it would probably be way better).

Comment: @Wooble See also - [Should we reopen a question if it is closed with a wrong reason?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208756) (even if I did think closing a "too broad" would be better, I don't think it "absolutely needs to be [changed]")

Comment: @Dukeling: well, ok, it was a protest vote to reopen based on the previous vote to reopen/undelete just so it could be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Wooble Voting to delete, again... (I don't think it's a particularly good pointer to the duplicate).

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend that you go and read [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) in the help section.

I don't really think someone here can be more specific than the Help Center itself **unless** you give us a specific question to look at.

Answer (score 2):

Your meta question, asking why your SO question was put on hold, was not put on hold.  It was just downvoted a lot.

Comment: actually, you closed it Servry.. I posted a link  to it

Comment: @KhanqueredPro Your first questions is just the question you were asking about before.  That's not a new question that was put on hold.  It's been on hold ever since you asked the other question.  The second question you linked to, as I said in my answer, is no on hold or closed, it is merely downvoted.  I have not voted to close either question.

Comment: @KhanqueredPro Please see the [revision history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/210208/revisions) of your [second question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210208/why-has-my-question-regarding-php-operators-been-put-on-hold) in which you can see that not only is it not on hold now, it have *never* been on hold

Comment: But was it really necessary to delete the original question? See my comment above.

Comment: @Pëkka It's a very poor quality question that did no research effort, is a duplicate, is too broad, and is a list question.  I see it as having no positive value (after the edits), nor do I see how it could be edited into a question that would have a positive value.  Given that, I felt deletion was appropriate.

Comment: @Servy re no research effort: I tried to find the duplicate by querying `php difference != <>` on Google on SO. Neither site produces an obvious result. SO turns up the "what does this symbol mean" question, but I would find overlooking that a forgivable offense for a newbie. Point is, the question was slightly different from the usual "how do I do <insert trivial thing here>" garbage and didn't deserve the treatment it got. And  why did none of the closers think of actually *closing* it as a duplicate?

Comment: @Pëkka With respect to research, one merely needs to look up "PHP operators" to see what each of the operators do to see that they are equivalent.  I consider standards for doing research/effort more than just "I googled the title of my question."  As for it not being closed as a duplicate, that would have been fine had it been done, but apparently the readers decided to just close it for problems with the question instead of taking the time to find a duplicate.  I also don't really see value in reopening a question just so that it can be closed again for a different reason.

Comment: @Servy I find not knowing the word "operator" also forgivable. Point is, the community decided to be bureaucrats where they could have provided a fine duplicate link with a minimum of good will.